# Where to create .aws/config in my django project?

Tags: django

how to add .aws/config in django project on this file structure

Hello I'm Studying Front-End Development and I was proceeding E-commerse Project with

pre-made API, and Design. but they suddenly shut down the server and gave me away the

backend Code without any explaination. the thing is I have no idea what to do.

So I excute following command from README

### Install Virtual Environment & Dependency

```
# ./backend
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py githooks
```

once I excute python manage.py githooks

it says

botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

### Set AWS Profile

vi ~/.aws/config

```
...
[profile incourse-commerce]
aws_access_key_id=**
aws_secret_access_key=**
region = ap-northeast-2
```

I think I should add my IAM credentials on this application but I dont know

where to add ./aws/config on this file structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqUbZ.png)

please help ㅠㅠ

Comment: Have you considered using AWS Secrets Manager? AWS recommends that you never add your AWS access keys directly to the client in any production files. Many developers have had their account compromised by leaked keys.